# Unable to match node containing forward-slash (/) using jackson library

Tags: java, json, string, jackson, unicode-escapes

I am unable to match node using jackson `JSONNode#at` method if JSON key contains `/` which is also used as separator in syntax of `at` method.

For instance in below JSON

```
{
    "message": "Hi",
    "place/json": {
        "name": "World!"
    }
}
```

we have key `place/json` which **includes `/` is part of key**.

If I use code like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonHiWorld = "{\"message\":\"Hi\",\"place/json\":{\"name\":\"World!\"}}";
    String message = mapper.readTree(jsonHiWorld).at("/message").asText();
    String place = mapper.readTree(jsonHiWorld).at("/place/json/name").asText();
    System.out.println(message + " " + place); // should print "Hi World!"
}
```

I am getting as output: `Hi`
But expectation output is: `Hi World`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `JSONNode#at` method matches nodes in JSON documents using JSON Pointer.  To match against the `/` character in a property name using JSON Pointer, you have to replace the `/` symbol with `~1`.

Try replacing

```
    String place = mapper.readTree(jsonHiWorld).at("/place/json/name").asText();
```

with

```
    String place = mapper.readTree(jsonHiWorld).at("/place~1json/name").asText();
```

See also the example in section 5 of [RFC 6901](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901#section-5).